# Como fazer um formulário dinâmico?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Implementei um script que adiciona dinâmicamente campos num formulário, no caso um formulário para adicionar produtos e a respectiva quantidade do mesmo.

O código está aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lzcn7dc/

Estou achando esse código muito burocrático, pois toda vez que o botão "NovoProduto" é acionado, é necessário fazer:

1. Clonar a div item
2. Alterar o id da div e dos campos produtoId e quant
3. Usar um contador para incrementar os ids e names, para garantir que não sejam iguais
4. Usar um atributo hidden (itemCont) para passar para o servidor a quantidade de novos produtos que foram criados, para saber quantas vezes terei que chamar $_POST["produtoId__"], pois pode haver centenas de produtos criados.

Gostaria da opinião dos colegas para aperfeiçoar esse código, tornando-o mais enxuto. Abaixo segue o código:

HTML:

```
<form action="cadastro.php" method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="button" id="novoProd" value="Novo produto"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
    <div id="item" class="item">
        <label>Selecione o produto:</label>
            <select id="produtoId" name="produtoId">
                <option value="1">Produto 1</option>
                <option value="5">Produto 2</option>
                <option value="9">Produto 3</option>
            </select>
        <label>Quantidade: </label>
        <input type="number" id="quant" name="quant"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="itemCont" value="1"/>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var itemCont = 1;
    $("#novoProd").click(function(){
        var novoItem = $("#item").clone();

        // modifica o id do item recem criado
        $(novoItem).attr("id","item"+itemCont);
        var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[1];
        $(novoSelect).attr("id","produtoId"+itemCont);
        $(novoSelect).attr("name","produtoId"+itemCont);

        var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[3];
        $(novoSelect).attr("id","quant"+itemCont);
        $(novoSelect).attr("name","quant"+itemCont);

        $("#formulario").append(novoItem);
        itemCont++;
        $("#itemCont").val(itemCont);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Recentemente tive a mesma necessidade e cheguei na mesma solução: Utilizando o clone.
Não acho que o código seja burocrático. obs: A diferença é que utilizava ASP.net MVC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma sugestão seria utilizar os nomes dos `inputs` como `Array` e tratar no PHP, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#novoProd").click(function() {
      var novoItem = $("#item").clone().removeAttr('id'); // para não ter id duplicado
      novoItem.children('input').val(''); //limpa o campo quantidade
      $("#formulario").append(novoItem);
    });
  });
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
  width: 50px;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
div.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="cadastro.php" method="post" id="formulario">
  <input type="button" id="novoProd" value="Novo produto" />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
  <div id="item" class="item">
    <label>Selecione o produto:</label>
    <select name="produtoId[]">
      <option value="1">Produto 1</option>
      <option value="5">Produto 2</option>
      <option value="9">Produto 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Quantidade:</label>
    <input type="number" name="quant[]" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

No PHP você faz um `foreach` no `POST[produtoId]` para fazer o `insert` na base

```
foreach ($_POST['produtoId'] as $key=> $value){
    echo $value; // Id do produto
    echo $_POST['quant'][$key]; // Quantidade
}
```

Isto evitaria as manipulações nos `id's` dos `input's`, reduzindo seu código jQuery e de certa forma simplificando o `insert` com PHP.

Comment: nesse caso o campo itemCont pode ser eliminado também

Comment: @Borachio, correto acabei de editar

Comment: Sim, a solução ficou muito mais limpa.

Comment: @abfurlan no exemplo acima, mostra como adicionar mais campos, e como seria para remover os campos adicionados? Pois somente adiciona...

Comment: @AlexandreLopes ficaria mais ou menos assim. https://jsfiddle.net/af2t19k7/1/, tem um problema se remover o primeiro, mas vc pode pensar em como tratar isso, mostrei apenas um exemplo.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes outra versão tratando o erro citado acima: https://jsfiddle.net/vx4j0myk/

Comment: Muito obrigado! @abfurlan excelente, bem completo!

Comment: @abfurlan tentei colocar os botões logo abaixo dos inputs, mas parece que estão sendo adicionados as `divs` depois dos botões, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/8td61mk4/

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Para resolver isso vc pode criar outra div e fazer o append nela. https://jsfiddle.net/ms4kf93t/

Comment: @abfurlan estou usando bootstrap, tive que fazer novas divs para agrupar cada label/input, fiz alguns ajustes e funcionou bacana. Só tem um problema... Ele não está limpando o valor dos novos inputs, ele pega o valor que colocar na primeira e joga nas próximas. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/tcofd0mj/1 - seria possível  também limitar por ex. max. 10 clones? Devo criar uma nova pergunta?

Comment: @abfurlan Consegui corrigir, apenas alterei **children** para **find** de `novoItem.children('input')`, para `novoItem.find('input')`. Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/j54nsky8/ --- Como seria para limitar os clones?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes para limitar você pode criar um if simples, https://jsfiddle.net/a6g29nvj/

Comment: @abfurlan Excelente! Adaptei ao meu código, funcionou 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Rapaz, fazer isso mais dinâmico você teria que escrever mais códigos. Mas os elementos poderiam ser removidos do seu html. Mas quando vou fazer algo do tipo que preciso de id dinâmico. Faço assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#novoProd").click(function(){
        var novoItem = $("#item").clone();
        var novoId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

        // modifica o id do item recem criado
        $(novoItem).attr("id","item"+ novoId);
        var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[1];
        $(novoSelect).attr("id","produtoId"+ novoId);
        $(novoSelect).attr("name","produtoId"+ novoId);

        var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[3];
        $(novoSelect).attr("id","quant"+ novoId);
        $(novoSelect).attr("name","quant"+ novoId);

        $("#formulario").append(novoItem);
    });
  });
```

Ou ao invés de salvar o contador em um elemento input oculto. Você poderia criar um atributo data. Por exemplo:

```
<form action="cadastro.php" method="post" id="formulario">
    <input type="button" id="novoProd" value="Novo produto" data-index="1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
    <div id="item" class="item" >
        <label>Selecione o produto:</label>
            <select id="produtoId" name="produtoId">
                <option value="1">Produto 1</option>
                <option value="5">Produto 2</option>
                <option value="9">Produto 3</option>
            </select>
        <label>Quantidade: </label>
        <input type="number" id="quant" name="quant"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="itemCont" value="1"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#novoProd").click(function(){
        var itemCont = $("#novoProd").attr("data-index");
        var novoItem = $("#item").clone();

        // modifica o id do item recem criado
        $(novoItem).attr("id","item"+itemCont);
        var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[1];
        $(novoSelect).attr("id","produtoId"+itemCont);
        $(novoSelect).attr("name","produtoId"+itemCont);

        var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[3];
        $(novoSelect).attr("id","quant"+itemCont);
        $(novoSelect).attr("name","quant"+itemCont);

        $("#formulario").append(novoItem);
        itemCont++;
        $("#novoProd").attr("data-index",itemCont);
    });
  });
```