# Como copiar um bloco html quando clicar em um link/botão?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Hoje eu e um amigo pensamos em desenvolver um sistema para cadastro de currículos, só que eu preciso que ao clicar em um link adicione mais 1 bloco de `inputs` cada vez que clicado. Eu tentei pesquisar, e não encontrei fontes agradáveis, ou seja não soube como pesquisar.

Vejam a imagem abaixo para entender melhor:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Obs: estou usando Codeigniter se ele tiver algum *helper* que faça isso.

Comment: Mostre o seu código. O que você já tentou?

Comment: Eu não tentei nada ainda, estou desde cedo procurando por algo sobre o assunto e não encontrei, então resolvi postar aqui pro povo tentar me ajudar. Como disse: Sou novo, e não tenho muita lógica.

Comment: Você deve ter feito alguma coisa. Senão, deveria começar do começo. Além disso, por que a tag JQuery? Por que você presume que a solução para o problema é em JQuery?

Comment: Porque eu sei que jQuery pode-se utilizar ajax para não recarregar a page. Já ví um exemplo quase parecido com o quero fazer, porém apenas escode e mostra.

Comment: Então você precisa fazer AJAX? Você deveria mencionar isso na pergunta. E, sim, JQuery tem facilidades para AJAX, mas não é obrigatório. JQuery é só uma biblioteca. Por que não começa tentando aprender a fazer o AJAX e, depois que já estiver conseguindo os dados (imprimindo na tela, por exemplo), volta e faz uma pergunta mais específica? É difícil responder perguntas tão amplas assim, mesmo que tentemos. Não seria uma resposta e sim um tutorial

Comment: Ok então galera, obrigado pelas informações, eu achei que fosse coisa simples e vocês iriam entender o que eu quero, mas ta tranquilo, vou procurar por fontes qualquer coisa eu crio uma resposta mais tarde, ou então eu consiga desenvolver uma pergunta mais específica. Desculpe-me

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO nao precisa pedir desculpas, só que não queira resolver tudo em uma pergunta só. Vá montando seu código, ou vendo exemplos aqui no site, e quando tiver uma dúvida sobre cada uma das etapas, pode perguntar separadamente como resolver cada uma. O importante é fazer a coisa acontecer passo a passo. Estamos todos aqui pra ajudar, mas é bom que as perguntas sejam bem objetivas. Tem umas dicas legais aqui: [ask] e no [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699) tem umas coisas que dão uma noção melhor de como o site funciona.

Comment: Tudo bem então, obrigado @Bacco e Plabo

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO Veja se isso aqui te ajuda: **[Como fazer um formulário dinâmico?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39714)**.

Comment: @Bacco, isso vai me ajudar em outra coisa, incrível, mas não é isso que eu queria, mas acabei achando aqui no Stack Over Flow mesmo, é isso que pretendo fazer: http://jsfiddle.net/MDL48/

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO ótimo que encontrou. Dê uma lidinha nos links que eu recomendei, sobre como perguntar, assim quando você tiver dúvidas e fizer novas perguntas, pode aproveitar melhor o site. A comunidade vai ter mais facilidade de ajudar se a pergunta for mais objetiva (e contiver algum código pra ser usado como base). Assim, você "ajuda a gente a te ajudar" :)

Comment: Opa, tudo bem @Bacco vou ler agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja só:

- Se inserir vários `<input>` sem atributo `name`, eles nem serão submetidos.
- Se inserir vários `<input>` com o mesmo valor no atributo `name`, somente o último será submetido.

Isso que você está querendo fazer merece um pouco mais de cuidado, não é simplesmente inserir um `<input>` atrás do outro. Aliás, pode até ser, desde que não precise recuperar esses dados posteriormente e acredito que o objetivo não é esse.

O que você pode fazer é:

- Ter vários `<input>` com o atributo `name` sendo um array. No servidor você por iterar sobre esse array e recuperar os dados. Por exemplo:

```html
<input type='text' name='empresas[]' placeholder='Nome da empresa 1'/>
<input type='text' name='empresas[]' placeholder='Nome da empresa 2'/> <!-- s/ problemas -->
```

---

Ou então...

- Definir o valor do atributo `name` sendo `empresa-x`, onde `x` é o "índice do campo" e este número que deve ser incrementado cada vez que um novo `input` for inserido no formulário. Nesse caso você deve clonar o último elemento, incrementar o valor de `x` e inserir no final do formulário.

```html
<input type='text' name='empresa-1' placeholder='Nome da empresa 1'/>
<input type='text' name='empresa-2' placeholder='Nome da empresa 2'/>
<!-- ... -->
```

A primeira é mais simples, pois só é preciso clonar o elemento. A segunda é um pouco mais chata de fazer por ser necessário incrementar o número do índice e substituir todos os atributos `name`, mas nada complicado. Vai depender de como você quer obter esses dados no servidor mais tarde.

## Clonando com Array

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.info-block:first').clone().insertAfter('.info-block:last');
  });
});
```

```css
.info-block { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>
 
  <!-- bloco que será clonado -->
  <div class='info-block'>
    <input type='text' name='empresas[]' placeholder='Empresa'/>
    <input type='text' name='escolas[]' placeholder='Escola'/>
    <!-- outros campos... -->
  </div>
</div>

<button>Adicionar + campos</button>
```

## Clonando incrementando

Nesse segundo exemplo, para ficar mais fácil controlar o índice eu criei um `<span>` como se fosse um contador. Por meio dele é possível obter o último índice para incrementá-lo e clonar o bloco.

```js
$(function(){

  $('button').on('click', function(){
    
    var $bloco = $('.info-block:last').clone(), 
        indice  = parseInt($bloco.find('span').text()) + 1; 
    
    $bloco.find('span').text(indice);
    $bloco.find('input[name^="empresa-"]').attr('name', 'empresa-' + indice);
    $bloco.find('input[name^="escola-"]').attr('name', 'escola-' + indice);
    
    // Se ouver outros inputs, altera o atributo name deles com o índice
    
    $bloco.insertAfter('.info-block:last');
  
  });
});
```

```css
.info-block { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>

  <!-- bloco que será clonado -->
  <div class='info-block'>
    <span>1</span>
    <input type='text' name='empresa-1' placeholder='Empresa' />
    <input type='text' name='escola-1' placeholder='Escola' />
    <!-- outros campos... -->
  </div>
</div>

<button>Adicionar + campos</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, melhor que o que tinha feito antes muito obrigado @renan

Comment: renan, estou envolvido em um projeto parecido, então preciso fazer isso novamente... tem como gerar os `name` diferente? exemplo `name="experiencia1"` `name="experiencia2"` name="experiencia3", desculpa reativar o tópico, mas preferi reutilizar do que criar outro.

Comment: O segundo exemplo não resolve? Clonar incrementando.

Comment: Deu certinho valeu.

Comment: @RenanGomes como seria pra remover um bloco clonado?

Answer (score 2):

Supondo o html:

```
<div class='dados'>
  <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnAdd">+</a>
```

Ao clicar no botão, através de um evento jQuery, você resolve o problema:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    $(".dados").append('<input type="text" value="" />');
});
```

Teste com este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fko1Lsph/)

Comment: Vou testa-lo, se funcionar marco como resolvido, mas uma dúvida, no lugar no `append('posso trocar aqui pra o id da div que quero que duplique?')`

Comment: se quiser duplicar uma div com um determinado id, pode sim: `$(".dados").append($("#id_da_div_para_duplicar"));`

Comment: Deu certo, porém troquei o append(), coloquei append("#formCursos") e ao invez de imprimir na tela o form, apareceu a string #formCursos

Comment: tá faltando o "$": `.append($("#formCursos"));`